# How to detect the resize of a view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When we double click on any view in eclipse or we resize it,how to detect the scenario in code. Currently my piece of code is extending ViewPart,now how can I detect the resizing in view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

    parent.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void controlResized(final ControlEvent e) {
            System.out.println("RESIZE");
        }
    });
}
```